# Metro last light starting weapons

Tags: metro-last-light

I'm wondering if ever get back your weapons that the nazis took from you when they captured you near the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't. You can "get them back" in the sense that you can find specific weapons later in the game, but the game never gives you back your original loadout you chose at the start of the game. This was intended to make the start of the game easy, so the difficulty could increase as the game progressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the weapons you started with at the spot where you can open the cell blocks, right before you open the next big door into the room, where the Führer is having his speech.

Comment: While you can find weapons there, those are not your confiscated weapons, that loadout is static a bastard gun and a shotgun.